# Born to do something or born for doing something / Made for doing something or to do something

Tags: prepositions, to-for

I was wondering if there is a difference between these 2 possibilities. In different songs I've heard:

- *'I was **born for loving** you'*,
  or
- *'**Born to be** wild'*,

but I don't get if there's a real difference or not.

Also, I tend to think that to express purpose it is rather used 'to + infinitive' when you're referring to verbs and 'for + noun', but it doesn't apply in the sentences above. Another example,

- *'These boots are **made for walking**'*, or
- '*These boots are **made to walk**'*

.
Can you please help me? Thanks in advance and greetings to all users!

Comment: "Loving" and "walking" are really gerunds, so in a sense, they are nouns.

Comment: You're talking about poetry, in essence.  The choice of words is not based on idiom but on the mood and nuance they convey.  There are no "rules".

Answer (score 1):

"Born ***to do*** something" means that it was your destiny to do that thing.

"Born ***for doing*** something" means that your innate characteristics make you ideal for doing that thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say both phrases are to do with destiny.

The phrase 'born **to do** something' is to do with a person's intention. So you are the actor of your destiny, a destiny you agree to, a destiny you embrace.

Whereas the phrase 'born **for doing** something' is to do with the function of an object, usually. So you are the toy of your destiny, you only serve a purpose, willy-nilly.